# How do I sort in Mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am using Mongoose and Express.

**package.json**

```
"dependencies": {
    "express": "3.4.8",
    "jade": "*",
    "mongoose": "*"
  }
```

In my routes, when I query a list of events like this:

```
Event.find({sort: {month: 'asc'}}, function(err, events){
    res.render('charity', { title: 'Charity', events: events });
});
```

Everything works great, and the app sends a list of events to the view. However, when I try sorting those by month (like this), I get an empty set:

```
Event.find({sort: {month: 'asc'}}, function(err, events){
    res.render('charity', { title: 'Charity',  events: events });
});
```

What is the proper way to sort?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`.find()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.find) function in mongoose actually returns a [query](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query-js) object. Though it is common to immediately pass in a callback after the query in find, you can chain to other methods, [`.sort()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-sort) is one of them.

So you where trying to declare a "sort" in the "query" section, but instead:

```
Event.find({}).sort({month: 'asc'}).exec(function(err, events){
    res.render('charity', { title: 'Charity', events: events });
});
```

Which is the longer form, but allows you to use the methods on the [query](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query-js) object.

Comment: Nailed it. `exec()` is what I was looking for!